# Contoso mvc3 system, many to many relationship

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have been following the Microsoft Contoso MVC3 University Tutorial located [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

I have a question regarding one area, In part 6; the tutorial explains how to create a table of courses an instructor can be assigned to using checkboxes. Specifically from the heading “adding Course Assignments to the Instructor Edit Page” onward

It seems overly complex, is there a more efficient way of doing things? Plug-in/built-in system etc.
What if you wanted to expand the system so an instructor had more than just Courses assigned to him? The duplication of code would be huge.

InstructorController

```
    // GET: /Instructor/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        Instructor instructor = db.Instructors
            .Include(i => i.OfficeAssignment)
            .Include(i => i.Courses)
            .Where(i => i.InstructorID == id)
            .Single();
        PopulateAssignedCourseData(instructor);
        return View(instructor);

    }

    private void UpdateInstructorCourses(string[] selectedCourses, Instructor instructorToUpdate)
    {
        if (selectedCourses == null)
        {
            instructorToUpdate.Courses = new List<Course>();
            return;
        }

        var selectedCoursesHS = new HashSet<string>(selectedCourses);
        var instructorCourses = new HashSet<int>
            (instructorToUpdate.Courses.Select(c => c.CourseID));
        foreach (var course in db.Courses)
        {
            if (selectedCoursesHS.Contains(course.CourseID.ToString()))
            {
                if (!instructorCourses.Contains(course.CourseID))
                {
                    instructorToUpdate.Courses.Add(course);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (instructorCourses.Contains(course.CourseID))
                {
                    instructorToUpdate.Courses.Remove(course);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void PopulateAssignedCourseData(Instructor instructor)
    {
        var allCourses = db.Courses;
        var instructorCourses = new HashSet<int>(instructor.Courses.Select(c => c.CourseID));
        var viewModel = new List<AssignedCourseData>();
        foreach (var course in allCourses)
        {
            viewModel.Add(new AssignedCourseData
            {
                CourseID = course.CourseID,
                Title = course.Title,
                Assigned = instructorCourses.Contains(course.CourseID)
            });
        }
        ViewBag.Courses = viewModel;
    }
```

edit.cshtml

```
    int cnt = 0;
    List<UniversitySystem.ViewModels.AssignedCourseData> courses = ViewBag.Courses;

    foreach (var course in courses)
    {
        if (cnt++ % 3 == 0)
        {
                        @:  </tr> <tr> 
                    }
                    @: <td> 
                        <input type="checkbox" 
                               name="selectedCourses" 
                               value="@course.CourseID" 
                               @(Html.Raw(course.Assigned ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "")) /> 
                        @course.CourseID @:  @course.Title
                    @:</td>
                }
                @: </tr>
            }
    </table>
</div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

ViewModels/AssignedCourseData.cs

```
    public class AssignedCourseData
    {
        public int CourseID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public bool Assigned { get; set; }
    }
}
```

A great deal of code to effectivly create this screen:
[image: Screen]

I guess you could generalise the helper methods used in the InstructorController, but that is no small task.

It seems such a fundamental component of CRUD systems to deal with one/many to many relationships; I am surprised I cannot find information on the topic.

TLDR: Is there a better way to associate objects to other objects using MVC3/Entity framework than what is shown above.

Edit2:
Here's an image of a quick Lightswitch application
[image]
A Candidate can have a number of Skills, Disabilities and Offences related to them. If i were to implement a MVC version of this system i would x3 of the code listed above to create the same effect.

Surely there is a more efficient solution.

Comment: "overly comples" is subjective. And that's a large tutorial. Why don't you post the relevant parts of the code with the question?

Comment: What *SPECIFICALLY* about this do you find overly complex.  Just posting the code, without localizing it to which specific code doesn't help us to understand your problem with it.  The code you posted is quite succinct actually, for everything it does.

Comment: That's because it's a lightswitch application.  MVC is a more "low-level" framework that gives you significantly more control over things.  More control comes at the price of having to do more things for yourself.  Lightswitch does what it does by reducing your flexibility.  MVC is about controlling every detail of the process, while still helping you to be as productive as possible.  Lightswitch is basically like the Forms Designer in Access, without the Access requirements.  You can do a lot with it, but you have a lot of limitations.

Comment: I should also point out, if you wanted to create a form that looked *IDENTICAL* to the MVC app in Lightswitch, how much code would it take?  I'm not talking one that functions similarly, i mean one that is identical.  You'd spend a lot of time doing what is extremely simple in MVC.  It's all about tradeoffs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, based on your comments, that you are looking for MVC to be Lightswitch.  If that were the case, Microsoft would not have developed Lightswitch.

Microsoft offers many technologies, MVC, Web Pages (WebMatrix), WebForms, LightSwitch.  Each has it's own unique strengths and weaknesses, and you choose the technology that fits your requirements the best.

If you're developing in MVC, you need to expend more effort in writing presentation code.  But, this extra effort gives you excellent flexibility in how that presentation works, what it looks like, and how it behaves.  If you don't want to do that, then I suggest choosing a different technology.